# Why $B_T\circ\theta_S=B_T$ with $(B_t)$ Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

In the Stochastic Calculus of Durrett Example 3.2.
[image]

I understand the usage of strong markov property. But I am confused about how $B_T \circ \theta_S=B_T$. Since $B_T \circ \theta_S(\omega(t))=B_T(\omega(t+S))$, is $T$ also shifted here? Because otherwise these two seems not equal. However, my professor says $T$ is not shifted, so I am very confused.
Could anyone help explain this? Thanks!

Comment: The title "A confusion in the book Stochastic Calculus of Durrett." is incorrect since the confusion lies in your mind, not in the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T$ is a *hitting time* and $T(\omega)>S(\omega)$ we can write 
$T(\omega)=S(\omega)+T(\theta_S\omega)$. Expressing the Brownian motion
explicitly as a function of two variables, i.e., $B_T(\omega)=B(\omega,T(\omega))$
we have 
$$B_T(\theta_S\omega)=B(\theta_S\omega,T(\theta_S\omega))
=B(\omega, S(\omega)+T(\theta_S\omega))=B(\omega,T(\omega))=B_T(\omega).$$